# C# Microsoft Cognitive Service Login

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using `Microsoft Cognitive Services` in Azure and want to create a `Cognitive Service` resources via C#.
So far I installed the following nuget packages:

- `Microsoft.Azure.Management.CognitiveServices v7.0.0`
- `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent v1.38.0`
- `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent v1.38.0`

I create my credentials like this:

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(ServicePrincipalApplicationId, ServicePrincipalSecret, TenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
```

and when I use `Microsoft Azure Fluent` like this I can successfully login

```
var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithSubscription(SubscriptionId);
```

but if I use

```
var client = new CognitiveServicesManagementClient(credentials);
client.SubscriptionId = SubscriptionId;

var properties = new CognitiveServicesAccountProperties(customSubDomainName: model.SubDomain);
var sku = new Sku(accountTier);
var parameters = new CognitiveServicesAccount(null, null, kind, location, resourceName, properties, sku);
parameters.Validate();

var result = client.Accounts.Create(ResourceGroupName, resourceName, parameters); // error here
```

I get an error message in `result` with

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.CognitiveServices.Models.ErrorException : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
```

How can I successfully create a new `Cognitive Service` resources in C#?

Answer (score 0):

To [create and subscribe to a new Cognitive Services resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-apis-create-account-client-library?pivots=programming-language-csharp#create-a-cognitive-services-resource-c), use the Create method. This method adds a new billable resource to the resource group you pass in. When creating your new resource, you'll need to know the "kind" of service you want to use, along with its pricing tier (or SKU) and an Azure location. The following method takes all of these as arguments and creates a resource.

```
static void create_resource(CognitiveServicesManagementClient client, string resource_name, string kind, string account_tier, string location)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Creating resource: " + resource_name + "...");
    /* NOTE If you do not want to use a custom subdomain name, remove the customSubDomainName
    property from CognitiveServicesAccountProperties. */
    CognitiveServicesAccount parameters = 
        new CognitiveServicesAccount(null, null, kind, location, resource_name, new CognitiveServicesAccountProperties(customSubDomainName : subdomain_name), new Sku(account_tier));
    var result = client.Accounts.Create(resource_group_name, resource_name, parameters);
    Console.WriteLine("Resource created.");
    Console.WriteLine("ID: " + result.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Kind: " + result.Kind);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```